# mod_auth_openidc how to access user variables for use in PHP

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf, mod-auth-openidc

I have `mod_auth_openidc` working on `centos7` but cannot find the documentation that references how to extract passed user information.

My logs show that the module is performing the following interrogations

```
oidc_authz_match_claim: evaluating key "nickname"
oidc_authz_match_claim: evaluating key "email"
oidc_authz_match_claim: evaluating key "user_id"
oidc_authz_match_claim: evaluating key "identities"
oidc_authz_match_claim: evaluating key "iat"
oidc_authz_match_claim: evaluating key "picture"
oidc_authz_match_claim: evaluating key "last_password_reset"
oidc_authz_match_claim: evaluating key "name"
oidc_authz_match_claim: evaluating key "created_at"
oidc_authz_match_claim: evaluating key "app_metadata"
oidc_authz_match_claim: evaluating key "email_verified"
oidc_authz_match_claim: evaluating key "clientID"
oidc_authz_match_claim: evaluating key "folders"
```

I have tried setting both of the following in httpd.conf

```
OIDCRemoteUserClaim email
OIDCOAuthRemoteUserClaim email
```

then using `<?php echo $_SESSION['REMOTE_USER']; ?>` but I am not getting any variables being returned.

thanks
Art

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the default setup the `email` claim is available both as an environment variable:

```
echo $_SERVER['OIDC_CLAIM_email']
```

and as an HTTP header:

```
$hdrs = apache_request_headers();
echo $hdrs['OIDC_CLAIM_email'];
```

the `REMOTE_USER` variable is accessible through:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'];
```

and will be set to a globally unique identifier by default but is configurable through the `OIDCRemoteUserClaim` directive as you showed. A few remarks about the setup:

1. You'll note that the HTTP headers are also available in the environment variables, with their variable names prefixed with `HTTP_` and uppercased e.g.
   `$_SERVER['HTTP_OIDC_CLAIM_EMAIL'];`
2. You can configure the behavior around passing claims in headers and/or environment variables through various configuration directives
3. The variables will of course only exist if the associated claim was present in the `id_token` or returned from the user info endpoint

Comment: Your answer pointed me to my basic error using `SESSION` instead of `SERVER`, but the tips on `OIDC_CLAIM_*` will change the approach to our architecture to simplify the process. Thanks for the detailed answer